# Load outlook email template (.oft) via win32com

Tags: python, email, templates, outlook, win32com

I like to load an outlook email template (.oft) via win32com for automation. I like to do something along this lines:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

#mail.Open() does not exist... but what instead?
mail.Open('Template1.oft')

mail.HtmlBody = alterEmail(mail.HtmlBody)
mail.Display(True)
mail.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate` instead of `Application.CreateItem`.